# Database Locked even after disposing all commands

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, executenonquery

The database is locked error appears even after I have disposed all the commands. I'm trying to write to the database and it is failing on the INSERT command at the bottom. I had it working before but for some reason it has started to fail now.

```
Sub Btn_SubmitClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    If MsgBox("Are you sure?",vbYesNo,"Submit?") = 7 Then
        'returns to previous screen
    Else
        'commences insert into database

        Rows = (dataGridView1.RowCount - 1)

        While count < rows 

            'putting grid stuff into variables
            DateStart = dataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(0).Value.ToString
            DateEnd = dataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(2).Value.ToString 'note other way round
            TimeStart = dataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(1).Value.ToString
            TimeEnd = dataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(3).Value.ToString
            TotalHours = dataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(4).Value.ToString
            OccuranceNo = dataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(5).Value.ToString

            'fetching reason ID for Storage

            SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand

            SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT Reason_ID FROM Reasons WHERE Reason_Name = '" & dataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(6).Value.ToString & "'"

            SQLreader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader

            ReasonID = SQLreader("Reason_ID")

            SQLcommand.Dispose

            'fetching site ID for storage
            SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand

            SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT Site_ID FROM Sites WHERE Site_Name = '" & dataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(7).Value.ToString & "'"

            SQLreader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader

            SiteID = SQLreader("Site_ID")

            SQLcommand.Dispose

            Oncall = dataGridView1.Rows(Count).Cells(8).Value.ToString

            'increment counter
            Count = Count + 1

            'send to database

            SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand

            SQLcommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Shifts (Staff_ID, Date_Shift_Start, Date_Shift_End, Time_Shift_Start, Time_Shift_End, Total_Hours, Occurance_No, Site_ID, On_Call_Req, Rate, Approved, Reason_ID) VALUES ('" & userID & "' , '" & DateStart &"' , '" & DateEnd & "' , '" & TimeStart & "' , '" & TimeEnd & "' , '" & TotalHours & "' , '" & OccuranceNo & "' , '" & SiteID & "' , '" & Oncall & "' , '"& "1" & "' , '" & "N" & "' , '" & ReasonID & "')"          
            SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            SQLcommand.Dispose

        End While



        MsgBox("Ok")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just tried that and It returns an error at compiling saying it is not a member of SQLcommand :/

Comment: You should be using SQL Parameters rather than string concat for the SQL.  This is *especially* important with SQLIte which is typeless.  Unless you have check constraints on each column, you can poke strings into integer columns very easily. if you take 15 mins to learn how to use a DataAdapter that can all be replaced by 1 line of code.

Comment: I'd also suggest that you use `Using` clauses so it disposes of the objects automatically on the `End Using`. When stepping through does it give the locked message on first insert, all inserts, random??? Not by chance also using another program to view/alter database contents? Any chance the file got set to read-only?

Comment: Off topic, but you should also move to the newer `MessageBox.Show` rather than obsolete `MsgBox`. Use enumerations (`vbNo`) rather than the integers (7) to make your code more readable.

Comment: This is the only insert command I currently have in the whole of the system. I can add directly into the database through SQLAdmin but not sending across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things which ought be changed in the code shown.  Since none of the `Connection`, `Command` or `Reader` objects are declared in the code, they must be global objects you are reusing. **Don't do that.**

There can be reasons for one persistent connection, but queries are very specific in nature, so trying to reuse `DbCommand` and `DataReader`s can be counterproductive.  Since these work closely with the `DbConnection`, all sorts of bad things can happen.  And it means the root of the problem could be *anywhere* in your code.

The following will loop thru a DGV to insert however many rows there are.

```vb
Dim SQL = "INSERT INTO Sample (Fish, Bird, Color, Value, Price) VALUES (@f, @b, @c, @v, @p)"

Using dbcon As New SQLiteConnection(LiteConnStr)
    Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(SQL, dbcon)

        dbcon.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@f", DbType.String)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@b", DbType.String)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@c", DbType.String)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@v", DbType.Int32)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p", DbType.Double)

        Dim fishName As String
        For Each dgvR As DataGridViewRow In dgv2.Rows

            ' skip the NewRow, it has no data
            If dgvR.IsNewRow Then Continue For

            ' look up from another table
            ' just to shorten the code
            userText = dgvR.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
            fishName = dtFish.AsEnumerable().
                              FirstOrDefault(Function(f) f.Field(Of String)("Code") = userText).
                              Field(Of String)("Fish")
            ' or
            'Dim drs = dtFish.Select(String.Format("Code = '{0}'", userText))
            'fishName = drs(0)("Fish").ToString()

            cmd.Parameters("@f").Value = fishName
            cmd.Parameters("@b").Value = dgvR.Cells(1).Value
            cmd.Parameters("@c").Value = dgvR.Cells(2).Value
            cmd.Parameters("@v").Value = dgvR.Cells(3).Value
            cmd.Parameters("@p").Value = dgvR.Cells(4).Value

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Using
```

- NOTE: Like the original code there is no **Data Validation** - that is, it assumes that whatever they typed is always valid. This is rarely a good assumption.
- **The code implements `Using` blocks** which will declare and create the target objects (dbCommands, connections) and dispose of them when done with them.  They cannot interfere with code elsewhere because they only exist in that block.
- **SQL Parameters** are used to simplify code *and specify datatypes*.  A side effect of concatenating SQL as you are, is that *everything is passed as string!*  This can be very bad with SQLite which is typeless.
- I would avoid firing off multiple look up queries in the loop.  The original code should throw an `InvalidOperationException` since it never `Read`s from the `DataReader`.

  - Perhaps the best way to do this would be for `Sites` and `Reasons` to be  `ComboBox` column in the DGV where the user sees whatever text, and the `ValueMember` would already be available for the code to store.
  - Another alternative shown in the answer is to pre-load a `DataTable` with the data and then use some extension methods to look up the value needed.
  - If you "must" use readers, implement them in their own `Using` blocks.
- A `For Each` loop is used which provides the actual row being examined.
- I'd seriously reconsider the idea of storing something like a `startDateTime` as individual `Date` and `Time` fields.

These are the basics if using DB Provider objects.  It is not certain that refactoring that procedure shown will fix anything, because the problem could very well be anywhere in the code as a result of DBProvider objects left open and not disposed.

One other thing to check is any UI Manager you may be using for the db.  Many of these accumulate changes until you click a Save or Write button.  In the interim, some have the DB locked.

Finally, even though the code here is shorter and simpler, using a `DataAdapter` and a `DataTable` would allow new data in the DGV to *automatically* update the database:

```vb
rowsAffected = myDA.Update(myDT)
```

It would take perhaps 30 mins to learn how to configure it that way.